# calling an Rcpp::Function in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

I have an R function that I need to call within a C++ program (which is later exported to R).
I would want to execute this R function in parallel, but so far I have not been able to do so.

Here is an example which *is working*, without parallelism

```
library(ergm)
library(Rcpp)
r_func <- function(theta, nnodes=100) {
  y = network(nnodes, directed=F) 
  as.matrix(simulate(
    y ~ edges, 
    theta0=theta))
}

sourceCpp(code='
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<arma::mat> test_seq(double x) {
  std::vector<arma::mat> res(100);
  Function r_func_ = Environment::global_env()["r_func"];
  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    NumericVector out = r_func_(x);
    int n_nodes = 100;
    res[i] = arma::mat(out.begin(), n_nodes, n_nodes); 
  }
  return res;
}
')
```

In order to get things done in parallel, my first try was to simply add a `#pragma omp parallel for` before the main loop.
However this produced an "R session aborted"

Another thing I tried was to modify the R function, to exploit R's parallelism like this

```
library(Rcpp)
library(ergm)
library(doParallel)

r_func_par <- function(theta, nnodes=100) {
  cl <- makeCluster(4)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  res = foreach(i = 1:100, .packages = c("ergm"),  
          .export = c("simulate", "network")) %dopar% { 
      y = network(nnodes, directed=F) 
      as.matrix(simulate(
        y ~ edges, 
        theta0=theta))
  }
  stopImplicitCluster()
  stopCluster(cl)
  res
}


sourceCpp(code='
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<arma::mat> test_seq(double x) {
  std::vector<arma::mat> res(100);
  Function r_func_par_ = Environment::global_env()["r_func_par"];
  Rcpp::List out = r_func_par(x);
  int n_nodes = 100;
  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    res[i] = arma::mat(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(out[i]).begin(), n_nodes, n_nodes); 
  }
  return res;
}
')
```

In this case instead, the code just hangs (for a very long time) and then R crashes.
Is there a better way to obtain this?

Comment: If you want to call an R function in parallel, you probably want to stay in R, and use something like foreach.

Comment: Unfortunately this call to a function in R is part of a big C++ code, and I need the rest of the C++ code to be in C++

Comment: 1. Calling R functions reduces speed to the speed of R functions, plus overhead.  2. Functions built with `sourceCpp()` or `cppFunction()` do not magically travel to parallel R instances.  You need your code in a package, and load the package on each client node.  That is well-known and has been discussed here numerous times.

Comment: Of course I do not expect a speedup from calling R from C++. 
However, as in C++ it's quite straightforward to parallelize C++ functions via openmp, I was wondering if it was possible to make calls to an Rcpp::Function in parallel within C++

Comment: Any calls to R’s C API, which includes calling an R function from C++, is ‘experts only’ according to ‘Writing R extensions’. I have always interpreted that as a MUST NOT.

Comment: I mean, first example I showed works correctly and I am by no means an expert. I was just asking the experts here if they know a way to make this run in parallel. If it's not possible I'll live with the speed I can get :)

Comment: You could try something like an `omp critical` section around the R call, but I'm not sure if that will work.